# entity refresh during save/update using SPRING DATA JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA in Spring Boot.

After an entity saved to database using Spring Data Jpa Repository, I am not getting whole entity. i.e., getting only the values which I passed to save().

So, I have checked google/SO and then added entityManager.refresh(organization). Now I am getting whole entity and mapped entities too.

Enterprise entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enterprise")
public class Enterprise extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "enterprise_id")
    private Long enterpriseId;
    @Column(name = "enterprise_external_name", length = 150, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String enterpriseExternalName;
    @Column(name = "enterprise_internal_name", length = 150, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String enterpriseInternalName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true, value = { "enterprise" })
    private Set<Organization> organizations;
    //getter and setters
}
```

Organization entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "organization_id")
    private Long organizationId;
    @Column(name = "organization_name", length = 150, unique = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "OrganizationName can't be empty !")
    private String organizationName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "enterprise_organization", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id") })
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true, value = { "organizations" })
    private Enterprise enterprise;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Controller class:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> addOrganization(@Valid @RequestBody Organization organization)
{
    ValidationResponse response = new ValidationResponse();
    response.setMessage(organizationService.addOrganization(organization));

    return new ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class OrganizationServiceImpl implements OrganizationService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;      
    public Organization addOrganization(Organization organization) {
        organization.setCreatedDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        organizationRepository.save(organization);
        entityManager.refresh(organization);
        return organization;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
}
```

Request body:

```
{
    "organizationName":"org5",
    "enterprise":{
        "enterpriseId":2
    }
}
```

Response If I don't include **entityManager.refresh(organization)**:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": {
        "createdBy": 0,
        "updatedBy": 0,
        "createdDate": 1510140158654,
        "updatedDate": null,
        "organizationId": 14,
        "organizationName": "org5",
        "enterprise": {
            "createdBy": 0,
            "updatedBy": 0,
            "createdDate": null,
            "updatedDate": null,
            "enterpriseId": 2,            
            "enterpriseName": null,
            "active": true
        },
        "active": true
    },
    "errors": null
}
```

But the problem I found was, its hitting the database again and selecting the data. It will be a performance issue if I have more mappings and also in every service class method I need to add entityManager.refresh().
Is this only way to refresh the entity after save/update ? Or can we avoid this by adding any configuration etc.. ? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating your "organization" object?. If you either create or retrieve inside the addOrganization() method then do save, you should be fine. As a best practice, service layer should deal with Domain objects and not the controller unlesss you are using OpenSessionInViewFilter to pass the domain to controller and view.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding Controller class. Please check. FYI, we are implementing only the REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your problem is with this line in your service.

```
organizationRepository.save(organization);
```

Instead of returning your parameter object return the return value from the save method.

```
public Organization addOrganization(Organization organization) {
    organization.setCreatedDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    return organizationRepository.save(organization);;
}
```

EDIT:

After rereading the question my answer is totally useless. You probably have to provide the whole entity to the save method or if you want to stick to update single fields, get it from the repository and set the fields on the entity. No need to save then, as the transactional write behind will take care of persisting the changes.

Comment: @c-weber You mean to say, I need to get the entire entity using the Id that was returned from the save() ?

Comment: I will edit my answer to make it more clear what I mean. The save method returns not only the ID it returns the whole entity.

Comment: @c-weber I tried that already, but not worked. organization and value return from the save() both are same. save() just updating the ID field, not more than that.

Comment: @c-weber I have updated the question with Request and Response. Please have a look.

Comment: Oh you want to UPDATE an existing organisation. I should have been more careful when reading your question. Well that is a different story then. As far as I know you can´t provide only a few fields of an entity to save method. More so with no ID set. In this case it will treat it as a new organisation and make an insert, not an update. I am lost why the refresh is even working. Could you provide the code for organistion entity?

Comment: @Krishna - This answer should work!! I wonder why its not working for you! As @Weber mentioned you should return the updated instance from your service layer like so `return organizationRepository.save(organization);`

Comment: @c-weber you misunderstood my problem. I am trying to create new entry in organization (which will be mapped to existing enterprise i.e, "enterpriseId":2).

Comment: @C.Weber I have updated the question with Entities. Please have a look.

Comment: I have to admit I am only guessing now. Since you specified no CascadeType on your ManyToOne mapping the Enterprise entity has only the ID set until you refresh it. At that moment it gets populated from DB.

Comment: @C.Weber I forgot to ask you one thing. Organization->Enterprise is the child to parent relationship. In that case I don't think we have to add cascade Type. Please suggest

Comment: What you have here is a bidirectional OneToMany relationship and that is not so easy to manage as one might think. Have you read about these kinds of relationships? I find @Vlad Mihalcea blog post about JPA, Hibernate very helpful. Take a look at this article for example. https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/03/29/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/#more-7143  Maybe this can help you solve your problems.